# Show baseball stats in a table for iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, objective-c-2.0

I want to know how to enter baseball stats manually in a table like hr, RBI AVG with tabs and all that. Is there a table that i can use for my iphone app? I want to use a navigation table and link to a table with the stats in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `UITableView` with a `UINavigationController` to create a hierarchy of screens, so your users can drill down from (say) a list of players, to the player's stats, then perhaps a detail view or a `UITextView` or a `UIPickerView` to change those stats. There are countless examples of using `UITableView`s in Apple's sample code library.

Have a look at how the Contacts app works as that's a good place to start. If you come up with a basic design with screen mockups, it will be much easier to answer this question.

Comment: Where would i store the stats so i can easily access them at once for my app? Would i have to store the stats in an excel file?

Comment: I've never used an Excel file as a data store on the iPhone, and I suspect that it would be difficult to use. I would use SQLite3 (built-in), or if the app is for 3.0+ devices, Core Data, for storing data. I would also create a "model" object (think MVC) for interacting with the data store, that all the view controllers talk to for information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link at [Google support](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068) to what you might be looking for.

If you have a Google account (e.g. Gmail) you can download Google Docs to your phone. Here's a [tutorial from Google](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3423701?hl=en).

1-click to select, 2-clicks to edit.

[image]